# How to load JSON to web page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I`m trying to get JSON data from an API and add is to HTML select option

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="school"></select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    schools();
});
function schools(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/sms/public/api/schools",
            method:"GET"
        }).done(function(data){
            var sch;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                sch = '<option>'+ data[i].name +'</option>';
            }
            $('#school').append(sch);
        })
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the code is displaying nothing.
Below is the sample json data provided by the api

```
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sample Academy" 
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Testing Academy" 
}
]
```

Comment: have you debugged requests/responses? Can you show us what have you done to solve that problem?

Comment: Any debugging efforts of your own? Open your console, read any error, look into the Network tab, etc.

Comment: is there any error in your console?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code also?

Comment: @AliyuHeidarUmar Don’t put relevant code in comments. Instead, [edit] your question and include it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your problem ? and your HTML code but try to do that:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"http://localhost/sms/public/api/schools",
   method:"GET"
}).done(function(data){
   var sch, i, json;
   json = JSON.parse(data);
   for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     $('#school').append('<option>'+ json[i].name +'</option>');
   }
});
```

if you receive data from a server, in JSON format, you can use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert a JSON format, into a native JavaScript object.